# Looping Through A ListViews Checked Items to Execute A Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures

What I have is a `ListView` with check boxes for each item in the list.

On a button click, I collect my 'checked items' like this;

```
ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection checkedItems = emps.CheckedItems;

            List<string> attend = new List<string>();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in checkedItems)
            {
                attend.Add(item.Text);
            }
```

I know this is working because I printed out the contents like so;

```
string s = String.Join(",", attend); MessageBox.Show(s);
```

However, I want to take these `strings` and run a SQL stored procedure for each string in my list (`attend`).

Like so;

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("my_SP", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (string item in attend)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", item));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Course", attender.SelectedValue));
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            con.Close();
```

**This works perfectly when I check only one item in the list, when I check more than one item it fails.**

The error message is;

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

I've tried changing the variable names of the commands etc, and I don't see where a `DataReader` is open, I haven't encountered this error before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach when opening a connection

```
using (SqlConnection conn  = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    Sqlmd.Connection = conn;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sqlmd);
   //...etc
}
```

Comment: @Clev231, When opening connections, especially if you are looping, enclose what you are doing with the "Using" to dispose of everything when ready. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Because inside the loop you use

```
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

this, at first loop opens an SqlDataReader (it is unassigned but it's still there) and then, when  you reexecute the loop the unused SqlDataReader is still blocking the connection.

Instead use

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Really ExecuteReader should be used when you need to read data from the database, not when you need to do an insert, update, delete operation, so your code should be changed in this way

```
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("my_SP", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", ""));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Course", ""));
        foreach (string item in attend)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = item;
            cmd.Parameters["@Course"].Value  = attender.SelectedValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
```

Also the parameter could be declared and added outside the loop changing only the value inside the loop. This will give a little more speed

Comment: Can you explain to me how the accepted answer has resolved your problem? I can't understand, certainly the using statement is beneficial but the error message should still be there.

Comment: Yes, it made me understand that I am trying to reopen the reader I have declared several times which led me to my answer below.. However I understand your solution would have worked too, hence why I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
            con.Open();


            foreach (string item in attend)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", item));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Course", attender.SelectedValue));
               SqlDataReader dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 dtr.close();
            }
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, it made me think there's something up with opening/closing my connection.

I got around it like this;

```
foreach (string item in attend)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", item));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Course", attender.SelectedValue));
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                con.Close();
            }
```

*Although perhaps it's inefficient to open and close a connection many times over.*